Turn off filter highlighting in Cascader
Using antdesign in react, I want to turn off keyword highlighting when filtering, how do I achieve this?
This is my code:
<Cascader
              multiple
              value={companyDefault}
              options={companyOptions}
              fieldNames={{ label: 'name', value: 'code' }}
              onChange={(e, selectedOptions) => handleChange(e, 'company', selectedOptions)}
              showCheckedStrategy={SHOW_CHILD}
              displayRender={displayRender}
              showSearch={{ cascaderSearch }}
            />
 const cascaderSearch = (inputValue, path) =>
    path.some((option) => (option.label as string).toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()));


I tried changing the interior, but to no avail
  .ant-cascader-menu-item-active {
    color: #333 !important;
  }

